# Calendars deprecated

Tags: ios6, calendar

```
if ([eventStore.calendars count] == 0)   
    { 
        NSLog(@"No calendars are found.");
        return NO;
    }
 EKCalendar *targetCalendar = nil;
 /* Try to find the calendar that the user asked for */
 for (EKCalendar *thisCalendar in eventStore.calendars){ line2
     if ([thisCalendar.title isEqualToString:paramCalendarTitle] &&
         thisCalendar.type == paramCalendarType){
        targetCalendar = thisCalendar;
        break;
     }
}
```

Line 1 and line 2 getting an error: "calendars deprecated : first deprecated in IOS 6"
How to resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

Instead you have to use the following method.

```
- (NSArray *)calendarsForEntityType:(EKEntityType)entityType;


NSArray *cals = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType: EKEntityTypeEvent];
```

And use the array `cals` in line2.

Check the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/calendarsForEntityType%3a)